# Type.IsPrimitive working for generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, reflection, types

If I write the following generic method:

```
static bool HelloWorld<TSource>(TSource input)
{
    return typeof(TSource).IsPrimitive;
}
```

and I pass an `int` to it, it successfully recognizes it as a primitive. If I pass a string for example, it will not - which means it works.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#remarks) states that it shouldn't work though, or am I miss-reading something?

> If the current Type represents a generic type, or a type parameter in
>   the definition of a generic type or generic method, this property
>   always returns false.

Comment: ~IsPrimitive is returning true because you're asking it about the type _of_ the generic parameter, not a generic _type_. It would return false for something like `typeof(Foo<int>)` which is a generic type where the type parameter is primitive.~ Sorry, I misread it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have kind of answered your own question... You said:

> I pass an `int` to it, it successfully recognizes it as a primitive

If you passed an `int`, then `TSource` *is* `int`, and is not a "generic type" or "type parameter".

When the documentation says "type parameter", it is referring to a `Type` object whose [`IsGenericParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenericparameter?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_IsGenericParameter) property is true.

You can get such a `Type` object by, e.g.

```
typeof(List<>).GetGenericArguments()[0] // this will give a Type object that represents a type parameter
```

Note the use of the unconstructed type `List<>` here, which is crucial.

To get the type parameter of your method, you need to get the `MethodInfo` of your method, and call `GetGenericArguments`.

Comment: ``To get the type parameter of your method, you need to get the MethodInfo of your method, and call GetGenericArguments.`` - you mean to say that if I wish to use reflection to get the generic method's argument, i'll have to do the above, right?

Comment: @SpiritBob I mean if you want to get the generic method's type parameter as a `Type` whose `IsGenericParameter` property is true, you need to use reflection.